# My opencv python program displays a seemingly expectant prhrase, but neither terminates, nor allows progress

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, opengl, ubuntu-12.04

I am having trouble with a program in which I 
want to perform a sobel derivation from openCV to find edges in a picture. I found a python adaptation of this code:
sobel_derivatives.html#sobel-derivatives
from the opencv tutorials
on this adress:
Official_Tutorial_Python_Codes/3_imgproc/sobel.py
which I wanted to copy and adapt to run on an image I found on the web. 
after having done abit of debugging, and running the program as "sudo", I simply get the message:

init done

opengl support available

and the prgram never terminates. I cannot use ctrl+c, or any other such commands (I am accessing my ubuntu OS from a puTTy client) my only option to retry, is to stop and restart my session.

My problem seems rather similar to this one:
init-done-opengl-support-available
but I cannot quite seem to work it out, nor am I able to post a further question on this thread. as far as I can tell, there seems to be an error in my openCV2. I tried to redownload it with a "sudo apt-get install", but no change. 
My code looks like this:

```
"""
Sobel_derivation.py

attempt at finding the derivatives in a picture.
this is extremely beginner-level coding, so please
bear with me. Might also take a look at the supposedly
more accurate 'Scharr' derivatives.

mostly imported and attempted to interpret from
https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python/blob/master/Official_Tutorial_Python_Codes/3_imgproc/sobel.py
"""

import cv2 # this is the currently installed version of openCV
import numpy as np # useful tool for most array-based computing

scale = 1 # for scaling the derivatives in the x and y direction
delta = 0 # optional value, here apparently set as trivial (also, mostly
#important for the 'Scharr' function from what I can see.
#ddepth = cv2.CV_16u # output image depth for 'scharr' function
ddepth = -1 #this should give the return image equal depth

img = cv2.imread('splash.jpg') # importing the image to be read from
# this directory, for simplicity

img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3),0) # calling the function from cv. img
# is the previous image and (3,3) seems to be the size. the point of
# the function is to smooth the image to reduce noise.

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)# the function returns a
# colour gray, greyscale of the image.


# time for the gradient in the x-direction
grad_x = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth, 1,0, ksize=3, scale=scale, delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
# grad_x = cv2.Scharr(gray,ddepth, 1,0)
#now for y
grad_y = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth, 0,1, ksize=3, scale=scale, delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
# grad_y = cv2.Scharr(gray, ddepth, 0, 1)

abs_grad_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_x) #converting back to uint8
abs_grad_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_y)

dst = cv2.addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, (0.5), 0)
#dst = cv2.add(abs_grad_x. abs_grad_y)

cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if you're running this from a console session ala putty, you probably can't even see the window that is drawn in the last 3 lines, and can't press any key on it to make the program stop regularily. maybe you can just skip the last 3 lines, and do a `cv2.imwrite("my.png",dst)` instead ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable X11 forwarding in order to open windows from a remote host to your local machine. If you use putty go to Putty Configuration > Connection > X11 and check enable X11 forwarding.

[image]

If you are connecting trough ssh simply add -X flag to you command e.g. 
`ssh -X username@remote-host.com`

The cryptic output

```
init done
opengl support available
```

was left there (minor bug I guess) by the developers and is printed anytime cv::imshow(..) is executed in a program.

Comment: The problem seems to have been resolved. It now displays a greyed out, and lined version of the picture on a screen hooked up to the "home computer". I tried commenting out the last three lines, resulting in the program simply running and shutting down. Including the lines again, now with and without the X11 turned on results in a displayed image. I still cannot terminate the process from my puTTy session, but on the "home computer", I can terminate it just fine. Thank you all for your help!